# AndroidStudio Crash on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-studio

I am using Android Studio on Ubuntu 16.04 and it just keep crashing, sometimes it doesn't even starts completely and it crashes!

I ran the **studio.sh** file in the terminal and here is the info dump on the terminal, the last part is around the time when the Android Studio crashed.

**Terminal Dump:**

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
WARN: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.tryActivate(SocketLock.java:184)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.access$300(SocketLock.java:50)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:124)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:113)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:157)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:113)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:263)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:101)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:91)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@7a4f0f29 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/media/mohit/776b997b-f9a1-46c2-92a0-7f438c7b78e3/mohit/AndroidStudio/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/mohit/.AndroidStudio2.1/system/tmp/jna-104073905/jna3415113200453289594.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/mohit/.AndroidStudio2.1/system/tmp/jna-104073905/jna3415113200453289594.tmp
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe367a2f587, pid=19294, tid=140614291318528
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xa27587]  SymbolTable::unlink(int*, int*)+0x87
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/mohit/java_error_in_STUDIO_19294.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

This just keeps happening a lot and I am completely unable to code anything.

Comment: You may see some more helpful logging output if you add a minimal log4j.properties file. http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install these dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html).

Try to take a look the permissions of files in the directory that you are installed Android Studio. Maybe you have a problem related with permissions.

SIGSEGV signal/error is a very generic error and it seems like a missing C library dependency.

> On POSIX-compliant platforms, SIGSEGV is the signal sent to a process
>   when it makes an invalid memory reference, or segmentation fault.

Comment: Installed the dependencies, still the studio is crashing with same SIGSEGV message. Also the directories are fine, no special permission required there. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Mohit Then suggest you to use 14.04 instead of 16.04. Perhaps 16.04 is using a different C / C++ library.

Comment: Btw just found a lot of similar problem, but they were faced by Eclipse.       Link :- http://askubuntu.com/questions/457506/eclipse-adt-crash-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled

Comment: No that is for Eclipse IDE can't seem to replicate the solution for Android Studio.

Comment: @Mohit Then look for similar questions for JetBrains because Android Studio based on JetBrains.